# Find a node with xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, find

I'd like to parse google geocode api respond, but the structure of the result is not always the same. I need to know the postal code for example, but it is sometimes in the `Locality/DependentLocality/PostalCode/PostalCodeNumber` node and sometimes in the `Locality/PostalCode/PostalCodeNumber` node. I don't really know the logic behind this, just want to get the value of the `PostalCodeNumber` node, no matter where is it exactly. Can I do it with XPath? If so, how?

**UPDATE**

Tried with `//PostalCodeNumber` but it returns an empty array. The code snippet is the following:

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
var_dump($xml->xpath('//PostalCodeNumber'));
```

The `$response` is the content of http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1055+Budapest&output=xml
(copy paste the url instead of clicking on it because of some character problems...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//PostalCode/PostalCodeNumber
```

Should do the trick.  A quick google search yields the following [schema snippet](http://schemas.stylusstudio.com/eml4/n2b3d787d/element_Locality.html), indicating that there may be multiple DependentLocality elements, nested, so you'll want to check for multiple results, and have some idea of whether you want the most specific (most deeply nested) or least specific.

**Update:**
To guard against namespace issues, explicitly add the namespace to the query:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$xpath->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0');
var_dump($xml->xpath('//ns:PostalCodeNumber'));
```

Update 2:  fixed a couple of typos

Update 3:

```
 <?php 
$result = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1055+Budapest&output=xml');
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0');
$search = $sxe->xpath('//c:PostalCodeNumber');
foreach($search as $code) {
  echo $code;
}
?>
```

Comment: It returns an empty array. :(

Comment: I suspect namespace issues...  try adding $xpath->registerNamespace('ns', "urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0");

Comment: Doesn't work. `$dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xml->AddressDetails->asXML());
    $xpath = new \DomXpath($dom);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('ns', "urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0");
    var_dump($xpath->query('//PostalCodeNumber'));`

Comment: that's what I get for eyeballing it, I suppose.  Take a look at Update 3, it's working on my machine

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this XPath:

```
Locality//PostalCodeNumber
```

It will find all descendants `PostalCodeNumber` of `Locality` element.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned the `Locality` node is not the root. I tried with `//PostalCodeNumber` in the root and in the `Locality` node but returns `array(0)`.

Comment: @haxpanel, `//PostalCodeNumber` should return all `PostalCodeNumber` elements. It seems your XPath engine doesn't work properly.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Should I open a new topic for this XPath engine issue?

Comment: @haxpanel, Update your question with additional info and sample input and source code.

Comment: @haxpanel, Provide sample XML.